# SSL Page Containing Elements that are not Secure

Tags: asp.net, security, ssl

I have an asp.net server serving up pages over SSL. However, it seems it is also serving up some content that is not over the secure connection, thus browsers are warning users that some content is not secure ("however, this page contains resources which are not secure..."). For the life of me I cannot figure out which content is causing this error. I've viewed the source of my page and cannot find any references to plain http:// content (Except in DOCTYPE, but removing that does not seem to change anything).

The main page I have been trying this on is here: https://encryptur.com/

Any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, the google ads in your page are not encrypted

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, disabled the ads and the warning is gone. The javascript source began with https, but I guess it must contain a reference to non https content. Googling reveals there is no https alternative. Oh well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to find the offending element....look for a request that doesn't have Https:

Comment: Great tool, first time I have used it. Thanks.

Comment: For stuff like this, I often use [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/).  Fiddler feels like overkill.

Comment: I like it, I like it a lot...nice to not have to set up filters or capture all the other traffic...too.

Answer (score 0):

[Burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html) is another option, an intercepting HTTP proxy.